# Same question from multiple users

Tags: cloud, crm-analytics

While answering email cases in Salesforce,if a number of users have been asking the same question how can one handle this situation efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

We use [Solutions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.sol_def.htm&type=5) for this purpose. You can create a number of Solutions, then attach those Solutions to a Case. You can enable Suggested Solutions to allow both the Support Team and Customers to have Solution Suggestions automatically listed, and even send emails using these solutions. There's a lot that goes into this, so I suggest you research the documentation for this.